# How to exclude only two symbols in a regex with \S+

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
(?<=^|\s|\w[;'])(@(\S+))
```

to take only the usernames. I used \S because in the website there are also a lot of asian with asian nicknames (and if I use \w i have problems).

But now I have to exclude symbols like , or . added at the end of the word. How to edit it?

Live version:
https://regex101.com/r/NEz05o/2

Comment: You could exclude it `(?<=^|\s|\w[;'])(@([^\s.,]+))` https://regex101.com/r/eUXM0A/1 and you can omit the second group if you only want the value without the @ `(?<=^|\s|\w[;'])@([^\s.,]+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this looks an interesting solution... what are the characters excluded by \b?

Comment: @J.Luca All non-word chars (non-letters, non-digits, non-underscores).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what is the difference between \b and \W ?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I overlooked one of the examples, you do not need `\b` here. `\b` is a word boundary and `\W` matches any non-word char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the `.` and `,` from the match using a negated character class using `[^\s.,]+` This will give you 2 capturing groups.

```
(?<=^|\s|\w[;'])(@([^\s.,]+))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eUXM0A/1)

If you only want the value after the `@`, you can use a single capturing group

```
(?<=^|\s|\w[;'])@([^\s.,]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O5PL11/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In the example link the is an entry with `It should take only "bongo" -> @bongo.caro` that is why I exluded the dot and the comma.

Comment: thanks! I need 2 groups, so I will use (?<=^|\s|\w[;'])(@([^\s.,]+))! Just the last tip. I noted that i can not take mike if i have ".@mike". Do you know how to fix?

Comment: @J.Luca In that case you can add the `\s` and the `.` to a character class `(?<=^|[\s.]|\w[;'])(@([^\s.,]+))` See https://regex101.com/r/RZY6wi/1